NodePort vs NGINX - my app fails when exposed as ingress
I have an app that works correctly in kubernetes when exposed through nodeport but when exposed as ingress, it doesnt.
I can get to the app without a problem, first screen is a login screen but when authenticating it doesnt do anything.
Request URL:
http://11.33.51.42/myapp/public/auth
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
200 OK
Remote Address:
11.33.51.42:80
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
access-control-allow-origin:
*
connection:
keep-alive
content-encoding:
gzip
content-type:
application/json
date:
Fri, 25 Oct 2024 10:41:23 GMT
transfer-encoding:
chunked
vary:
Origin
vary:
Access-Control-Request-Method
vary:
Access-Control-Request-Headers
vary:
accept-encoding,origin,access-control-request-headers,access-control-request-method,accept-encoding
accept:
*/*
accept-encoding:
gzip, deflate
accept-language:
es
connection:
keep-alive
content-length:
43
content-type:
application/json
cookie:
route=1729852248.774.9620.25433|2dcc187834e87b204907792b03103ee3
host:
11.33.51.42
origin:
http://11.33.51.42
referer:
http://11.33.51.42/myapp/resources/
user-agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/130.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/130.0.0.0
x-requested-with:
XMLHttpRequest

Request URL:
http://11.33.51.42/resource-manager/api/users/logged
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
401 Unauthorized
Remote Address:
11.33.51.42:80
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
connection:
keep-alive
content-length:
0
date:
Fri, 25 Oct 2024 10:41:23 GMT
vary:
Origin
vary:
Access-Control-Request-Method
vary:
Access-Control-Request-Headers
accept:
*/*
accept-encoding:
gzip, deflate
accept-language:
es
connection:
keep-alive
cookie:
route=1729852248.774.9620.25433|2dcc187834e87b204907792b03103ee3
host:
11.33.51.42
referer:
http://11.33.51.42/myapp/resources/
tgt_token:
TGT-54-HAJpydZProChdq83jA-QLTNBgFE0Ehnv2eMHDUYmVQbuqKxfKotAK0AnbUzXo3k7npk-agata.net
user-agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/130.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/130.0.0.0
x-requested-with:
XMLHttpRequest

I am stuck and i have tried loads of things. Would you please help me fowards? There might be info missing here that id be glad to share
i have tried many different ingress configurations but none work and i am not sure how to troubleshoot
